# Duda con smbus y raspberry - Endianess

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Estoy escribiendo un código para poder leer información de los registros de un sensor, en concreto el MPU9250 de InvenSense junto al AK8963 de AsahiKASEI y el BMP280 de BOSCH.

Sin embargo, para leer ciertas entradas de memoria necesito utilizar la instrucción `read_i2c_block_data` o `read_block_data` de la librería `smbus`. De hecho, me gustaría aprovechar para preguntar sobre cuál de las dos es mejor elegir. `read_i2c_block_data` puedes elegir la cantidad de bytes a leer (en este caso 8 bits); mientras que `read_block_data` te deja leer hasta 32 bytes. Presupongo, corregidme si me equivoco, que para ahorrar recursos es mejor utilizar `read_i2c_block_data` en vez de `read_block_data`.

Volviendo a la pregunta principal, el problema es que tengo que leer el registro para modificar solo algunos elementos de ese registro, para ser más específico, el registro GYRO_CONFIG (por si sirve de algo), del cual, solo quiero modificar los bits [4:3] y [1:0], correspondientes a la selección del fondo de escala y bypass del DLPF.

Para ello, tengo que leer el registro, guardarlo en una variable, modificar lo que necesito y volver a escribirlo en el mismo. Mejor pongo un poco de código para explicarme mejor:

```
    giro_cfg = bus.read_i2c_block_data(MPU9250_ADDR, GYRO_CONFIG, 1)
    # Modificaciones de giro_cfg
    bus.write_byte_data(MPU9250_ADDR, GYRO_CONFIG, giro_cfg)
```

El problema es: ̣**Cómo se trata el orden de bits en la comunicación entre el Raspberry y el dispositivo I2C (Endianess)?**.

Por lo que tengo entendido, Raspberry es bi-endian, pero trabaja en little-endian. Claro, si Raspberry es little-endian, pero la librería luego hace algún cambio a big-endian, el número del índice del vector `giro_cfg` variaría en un caso u otro.

A lo mejor me estoy liando yo solo y es más simple de lo que parece, pero llevo ya unos días dándole vueltas al asunto y no sé muy bien qué puedo hacer.

Muchas gracias de antemano a todos.

Comment: Puedes probar leyendo un registro con un valor conocido (segun el datasheet), e imprimirlo en python. Ahí te darás cuenta si tienes o no que preocuparte por el endianess.

Comment: Efectivamente, la solución más fácil ha sido esa y he conseguido solucionar el problema. Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Podrias publicar los resultados que obtuviste como respuesta a la pregunta. saludos

Comment: Si no entendí mal tu código, estás leyendo un solo byte. En ese caso la _endianness_ no interviene. Sólo afecta a la ordenación de los bytes dentro de un dato multi-byte, pero nunca a la ordenación de los bits dentro de un byte.

Comment: Te equivocas @abulafia, el endianess tambien interviene a nivel de byte. Cuando usas comunicaciones seriales en las que transmites un bit a la vez, debes saber si el byte `0x00001111` se transmite de izquierda a derecha o viceversa. De igual manera el almacenamiento en memoria se ve afectado por este. De allí salen los términos Little endian y Big endian, dependiendo del orden como se almacenan los bits, primero LSB o MSB (Least-Significative Bit y Most-Significative Bit).

Comment: No sé qué resultados puedo mostrar, porque al final esos bits son para configurar un registro y un modo de funcionamiento. Lo que sí que hice era leer un registro que contiene la ID del sensor (WHO_AM_I) y, viendo el número que me devolvía (en binario) al compararlo con lo que debería devolver, supe que era big-endian y que el bit 7 (MSB) del registro es el 0 en el código de Python. Todo esto suponiendo que el bit 7 sea el MSB, porque en el datasheet no dicen nada...

Comment: @gustavovelascoh No quiero entrar en polémicas, pues además el campo de las comunicaciones serie me es ajeno, pero en mi opinión, la interfaz que se ocupe de leer/escribir los bits por el cable serie ya los reordenará de forma apropiada, de modo que la CPU reciba un byte en el orden correcto. El concepto de endianness afecta sobre todo a la memoria y la ordenación de los bytes. Veo en [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Bit_endianness) una nota que parece darme la razón. ¿Realmente te has encontrado alguna vez con problemas de bit-endianness? (es por aprender)

Comment: Las comunicaciones serie también son algo nuevo para mí, pues es la primera vez que me enfrento a ellas de forma seria y ya que me enfrento a este reto, creo que lo mejor es hacerlo bien hecho y saber qué vas haciendo y no escribir código a lo loco. Problema como tal, nunca, pero la duda me asaltó cuando me encontré con el problema de querer modificar solo unos bits y dejar otros intactos. Además, quiero entender que si no se indica nada debe ser big-endian. De lo contrario, como ya he visto en el datasheet del AK8963, te indica que los registros están en little-endian.

Comment: Hola @abulafia, no es por entrar en polémica, estamos de acuerdo en la parte del endianess a nivel de memoria, esto lo he visto entre plataformas (microcontroladores) e incluso intercambiando datos a través de sockets entre C y Java. En la parte de comunicaciones, como menciona en el articulo de wikipedia, hay protocolos que determinan el orden de transmisión, primero LSB o MSB, ya que esta señal por lo general ingresa a un registro de desplazamiento, donde al terminar de recibir los bits se hace disponible para lectura. Saludos